# echo a random name from a list, vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm very new with programming, and I want to make a program that randomly selects a name or sentence from a list in Vb Script.

here is the list:

```
Jacob
James
Jason
Caleb
Ashlee
John
```

The program needs to choose a random name from that list.

If there is anyone who could help, I would very much appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do what you require in VBScript. You have to implement your own as below. 
Also, you might want to check these out:

- [Randomize Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38d7ckek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
- [Rnd Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e566zd96(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [Array Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxhtazh%28v=vs.84%29)
- [UBound Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
- [LBound Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65s334te%28v=vs.84%29)

```
Randomize

Function RandomWithinRange(min, max)
    RandomWithinRange = Int((max - min + 1) * Rnd() + min)
End Function

Function RandItemFromArray(arr)
    RandItemFromArray= arr(RandomWithinRange(LBound(arr), UBound(arr)))
End Function

Dim names
    names = Array("Jacob", "James", "Jason", "Caleb", "Ashlee", "John")

MsgBox RandItemFromArray(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim names,index
Randomize
names = Array("Jacob","James","Jason","Caleb","Ashlee","John","Mike","Ken","Mark","Kim","Cindy","Joe")
index = Int((UBound(names)+1)*Rnd())
msgbox names(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class Random as the index of the list.

```
Dim namesList As New List(Of String)
namesList.Add("John")
namesList.Add("Mike")
//etc
Dim randomNum = new Random()
Dim randomName = namesList(randumNum.Next(0, namesList.Count))
```

Comment: Where do I insert the list of names?

Comment: apparently this is a VB.Net solution, OP is looking for VBScript.